Changing the hamburger/TogglePaneButton color on mouse over in Kinnara's ModernWpf applications
I have a WPF application using Kinnara's ModernWpf (link)
To change the text color of all the NavigationViewItems in the sidebar as well as the hamburger/TogglePaneButton I just need to add this line in the <NavigationView.Resources> section:
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForeground" Color="Red" />

and it applies to all of them, but when I want to change the mouse over color by adding this line:
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver" Color="Gold" />

It only applies to the NavigationViewItems and not the toggle button (which is black for some reason).
Does anybody know how to change the color of that hamburger/TogglePaneButton button using only xaml?

